# How to counteract USB Rubber Ducky (or other bad USB) on Android devices?

Tags: security, usb

I've read somewhere that it's possible to use mouse and keyboard on Android devices. Because that's possible, it's also possible to use devices like USB Rubber Ducky to automate key presses to hack into an Android device.

So, how would I counteract that?

Comment: I'm assuming you are thinking of [a PIN brute force attack](https://github.com/urbanadventurer/Android-PIN-Bruteforce). If no root/no Custom ROM you are limited to: (a) if the device doesn't supports USB-to-Go / USB HID so a keyboard/mouse might not work (b) the default behavior of that ROM for a PIN / Pattern attack. You should clarify if root/Custom ROM are options.

Comment: afaik gatekeeper prevents too many attempts and increases timeout and depending on password strength it will factory reset after 30 attempts anyway - do some test